# Ensuring a client request is delivered the correct response

Tags: java, sockets

Looking for suggestions to the following problem.

I am working on an application(client) which uses a single TCP socket to read and write messages to a server.

A Message is one of several predefined types which will be parsed upon arrival.

The server may broadcast a message at any time.

A client will send a message to the server, and expect a response. However (and here is where my question comes in), I cannot read from from the socket to receive this message since I have no idea when it may be delivered. Most of the time the client response message will be delivered immediately after the client request. However, occasionally another broadcast message will be sent first.

The read channel of the socket is enqueued into a blocking queue by a single producer thread. In a separate consumer thread, any messages are dequeued and sent for further processing. In order to get the expected client responses, should I use an event source / listener idiom to have my clients be notified when their (and if) responses arrive?

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: I think my question is unclear, since the suggestions so far don't deal with the issue at hand. In the end, I did use the event source / listener idiom to deal with this. Again, thanks for the errort, but I consider this to be closed. A moderator may even want to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect opportunity to use Java's Serialization mechanisms. You can do something like this (assume you're catching all relevant exceptions, which are omitted for brevity)

```
class ClientListeningThread {

    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    ClientListeningThread(Socket s) {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOututStream());
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            ClientMessage message = (ClientMessage)in.readObject();
            engine.addMessage(this,message); // add to the message queue, signifiying which listening thread to give the response to
        }
    }

    public void send(ServerMessage message) {
        out.writeObject(message);
    }

}
```

Your messages can even have callbacks in them to

class LoginMessage {

```
public final String username;
public final String password;

public LoginMessage(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public void callback(ClientListeningThread thread, ServerProcessor engine) {
    ServerMessage response = engine.attemptLogin(username,password);
    thread.send(response);
}
```

}

And in your engine

```
while(!requests.isEmpty()) {
    ClientRequest request = requests.poll();
    ClientListeningThread = request.thread;
    ClientMessage message = request.message;
    request.callback(thread,this);
}
```

Comment: Don't see where serialization is coming into play here. Also, please see my edit. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using a listener and a cached thread pool. So you can create a Runnable class that does the processing of the message. Then create a listener class that simply instantiates a socket (or server socket) and creates a your thread pool. In your listener class create an infinite while loop that listens for incoming requests and pass the socket.accept into the constructor of your runnable object so that it can process any input from the socket.

Code will look something like this:

```
public class MessageHandler implements Runnable {

    String msg = "";
    Socket socket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    public void MessageHandler(ServerSocket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Message read from socket
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Message: " + in.readLine());

        //Reply send back through same socket
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED. THANKS.");
    }
}
```

And you listening class will look something like this:

```
public class SocketListener {

    ServerSocket socket = null;
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = null;
    Runnable runnable = null;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        socket = new ServerSocket(8181);

        /* Socket will always be listening, when a request arrives a thread will handle
         * the incoming stream.
         */
        while(true) {
            threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            runnable = new MessageHandler(socket.accept);
            threadExecutor.execute(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this code will compile but your server implementation can look very similar to this and will be scalable and robust.

Your client can be almost identical although you will use a *Socket* not a *ServerSocket* and maybe handle your message differently.